# DataTables : Dropdown On change

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, dropdownbox

First of all its not about filtering(searching) of drop-down.

I am using [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net) : where one of my column has drop-down , i want when i change or select any option from it ... its should  pass to it resp value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dt = $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "scrollY": "440px",
        "scrollX": "100%",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/server_processing.php",
        "deferRender": true,
        "aoColumns": [{
                className: "center",
                "class": "details-control",
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "",
            },
            { className: "center", },
            { className: "center", },
            { className: "center", },
            { className: "center", },
            { className: "center", },
            { className: "center", },

        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
           "aTargets": [7],
           "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
               $(nTd).css('text-align', 'center');
           },
           "mData": null,
           "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
              return '<td><select id="dynamic_select" name="dynamic_select">\n\
                              <option id="0" value="">Select</option/>\n\
                              <option id="1" value="test.php">1</option/>\n\
                              <option id="2" value="test2.php">13</option/>\n\
                              <option id="31" value="test3.php">12</option/>\n\
                           </select></td>';

            }

        }]

    });

    $('select[name=dynamic_select]').on('change', function () {
        var attvalue = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");

        var mainval = $(this).val();

        var url = mainval;

        if ($(this).children(":selected").attr("id") == 0) {

        } else if ($(this).children(":selected").attr("id") == 1) {
            window.open(url, "_self");
        } else {
            window.open(url, "_self");
        }

        return false;
    });

});
```

below is my HTML

```
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

All is working fine ... just  on change of select value .. i need it should go to ***resp. Url with its resp. id***

Also can i define each row a unique id ( or my database primary id ) ?

Note : if i put above jquery in my simple PHP then its working .. but don't know why its not working in data-tables

Please help me

Comment: Try changing this `$('select[name=dynamic_select]').on('change', function () {` to `$(document).on('change', 'select[name=dynamic_select]',function () {`

Comment: Have you tried [Column Filter Addon](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)?

Comment: @ Darren : thanks so much +1 ... i was struggling from 1 hr for this .. pls can you brief me about difference ..as i am new in it...also how i can make each select unique ...with any unique id to each

Comment: @hindmost .. my first line tell " First of all its not about filtering(searching) of drop-down. " .. means i don't want filtering ... its an extra column with drop-down

Comment: hey , what i did is added " _'+full[0]+' " on select now its look :
<select id="dynamic_select_'+full[0]+'" name="dynamic_select_'+full[0]+'">  where [0] is my primary id which is unique .. and on change i did "   $(document).on('change', 'select[name=dynamic_select_'+full[0]+']',function () { " -- its right ?

Comment: when i add '+full[0]+' in on change .. i am getting error " ReferenceError: full is not defined
 

$(document).on('change', 'select[name=dynamic_select_'+full[0]+']',function () " .. also my on change is stoped

Comment: pls help me.. any one here ?

Comment: full[0] is out of scope if you're using it your onchange method, you need to get the id from 'this' or 'e.target' when the selectlist is changed